how to integrate InstantSearch from Algolia in react Native App
I am trying to integrate InstantSearch from Algolia in a React Native App
The issue i am facing is that InstantSearch Provider from Algolia needs to wrap the root component App.js.
Whereas App.js is wrapped in Navigation Container for stack navigation, And NavigationContainer does not accept anything other than screen component, nor can I wrap NavigationContainer inside InstantSearch Component.
Now how should I integrate InstantSearch Provider from Aloglia in react native
App.js currently

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Product from "./screens/Product";
import Home from "./screens/Home";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={Product} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Requirement of Instant Search from Algolia (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/#add-instantsearch-to-your-app)
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import { InstantSearch } from 'react-instantsearch-core';

const searchClient = algoliasearch('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="instant_search">
          {/* ... */}
        </InstantSearch>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

I tried to integrate Instant search with Home.js , but it did not work
Let me know a proper way to integrate the Algolia InstantSearch with Navigation in App.js(root component)
